# arangosh: delete console history

Tags: arangodb

In `arangosh`, I have accidentally executed `require("org/arangodb/users").save("user", "password")` without the `console.history false` command-line option, and now the password seems to be permanently part of the history.

Is there any way to delete the command history of `arangosh`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be a file called `.arangosh.history` in your **user folder**.

The path depends on your operating system. It should be one of the following:

- `/home/<username>/.arangosh.history` on Linux
- `/Users/<username>/.arangosh.history` on macOS
- `C:\Users\<username>\.arangosh.history` on Windows